# Показать минимальное значение Double

Tags: java

Как правильно показать минимально отрицательное значение чисел типа double и float

```
//float
        System.out.println(Float.MIN_VALUE);
//double
        System.out.println(Double.MIN_VALUE);
```

Такой вариант не правильный так как он дает положительное значение.

Для double максимально отрицательным числом будет 
-1.7976931348623157 * 10 в степени 308. Как это отобразить в консоли?

Comment: `-Double.MAX_VALUE` https://stackoverflow.com/a/2389644/12191177

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ на этот вопрос будет следующего вида:

```
//float
        System.out.println(-Float.MAX_VALUE);
//double
        System.out.println(-Double.MAX_VALUE);
```